# Solr EDisMax issue

Tags: solr, lucene, edismax, dismax

I'm trying to get some documents from the index, with no luck.

I have a document like this

```
<str name="id">4</str>
<arr name="title">
<str>whatever thing</str>
</arr>
```

If you notice, the title says **"thing"**. This field type is "text_es", described just as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_es" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_es.txt" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.SpanishLightStemFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- more aggressive: <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Spanish"/> -->
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

If I do the following search:

[http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=thing&defType=edismax&qf=title^20.0+text^0.3](http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=thing&defType=edismax&qf=title%5E20.0%20text%5E0.3)

It returns nothing. It works on Solr 3.6, but doesn't work on Solr 5.2. I'm consuming everything using Solarium (PHP), but not sure how to fix this.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What fieldType are you using to index your title?

Comment: @alexf in my case, it is "text_es", which implements "SpanishLightStemFilterFactory"

Comment: Can you add it to your post?

Comment: @alexf done, with the fieldType as well

Comment: Thx, in your log of Solr admin, nothing is bad?

Comment: @alexf nothing on the logs. It actually executes, but it returns nothing.

Comment: You can use [luke tool](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases) to observe if your document is well indexed.